# VBA: Problem with getting last two recent files of specific folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to recieve the last two recent files of a specific folder and mostly my code is working fine:

```
Dim FileSys, objFile, myFolder, c As Object

  FolderName = ("C:\Users\asd\Desktop\Test\do\")
                Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(FolderName)

dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
        For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
            If InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".csv") > 0 Then
                If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
                    dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
                    strFilename2 = strFilename
                    strFilename = objFile.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next objFile
```

The problem I am having is, if the most recent file is from 2022 and the second most recent file is from 2021, the first objFile is the file from 2022 and he is not checking any older ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to keep track of both the most recently modified file and the next most recently modified file instead of just comparing to the saved most recently modified file date, `dteFile`.  This gets around the issue you described: finding the most recently modified file early, and therefore not recording the second most recently modified file as well.  If the two are separate variables, you can compare things to them independently.

Essentially, add a little bit more to what you are already doing:

1. Iterate through each file in the folder
2. If the file has been modified more recently than the previously saved file that was modified most recently (`dteFile` and `strFilename` variables), update the variables
3. If the file has been modified more recently than the previously saved next most recently modified file (`dteFile2` and `StrFileName2` variables), update the variables.

```
Private Function TwoMostRecentlyModifiedFiles(FolderName As String) As Collection

    ' Purpose:
    ' Return a Collection of the two most recently modified file names in a folder
    
    Dim FileSys As Object
    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(FolderName)
    
    Dim dteFile As Date, dteFile2 As Date, strFilename As String, strFilename2 As String
    
    ' Iterate through all files in the folder
    Dim objFile As File, DateLastModified As Date, FileName As String
    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
    
        DateLastModified = objFile.DateLastModified
        FileName = objFile.Name
    
        ' Check if the file has the most recently modified date
        If DateLastModified > dteFile Then
            ' The file's date is more recent than the previous one
            
            ' Replace the current most recent file date, and move the old most
            ' recent file date to the 2nd most recent file date
            
            dteFile2 = dteFile
            dteFile = DateLastModified
            
            ' Update the filenames
            strFilename2 = strFilename
            strFilename = FileName
            
        ElseIf DateLastModified > dteFile2 Then
            ' The file's date was more recent than the previous 2nd most recent file's date
            
            ' Replace the current 2nd most recent file date
            dteFile2 = DateLastModified
            
            ' Update the filename
            strFilename2 = FileName
            
        End If
        
    Next objFile
    
    Dim ReturnCollection As New Collection
    ReturnCollection.Add strFilename
    ReturnCollection.Add strFilename2

    Set TwoMostRecentlyModifiedFiles = ReturnCollection

End Function
```